# log4j path in production for tomcat 7 on windows

Tags: windows, tomcat, logging, log4j

I need simple path setting to use log4j to be used for logging FINEST level of logging. But all forums and discussions show path setting for log4j.properties file either under eclipse or in some dev env. For a non development user, i need to set log4j.properties file, i tried in C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\conf path, but dosent help. stdout logs show default logs, note I have deleted default ogging.properties from \conf folder.
Where do i put log4j.properties file in windows tomcat folder ?

Answer (score 0):

well, as official docs say (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html), you should have not deleted, the default logging.properites file, present on:

```
${catalina.base}/conf/logging.properties
```

,but rather add there what you need:

```
org.apache.catalina.level=FINEST
```

and

> You would need to ensure the ConsoleHandler's (or FileHandler's') level is also set to collect this threshold, so FINEST or ALL should be set.

Or is there any strict requirement for you to use `log4j` (as per default `JULI` is used by `tomcat7`)?

**UPDATE**:

OK, as you mentioned, you're interested in the log4j case only. Let me point you to the official documentation: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j

Please follow the steps present there. As they claim to be working :)

For the explicit points you mentioned, the location of the log4j.properties file:

> Create a file called log4j.properties with the following content and save it into $CATALINA_BASE/lib

```
log4j.rootLogger=FINEST, CATALINA

# Define all the appenders
log4j.appender.CATALINA=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.CATALINA.File=${catalina.base}/logs/catalina.
log4j.appender.CATALINA.Append=true
log4j.appender.CATALINA.Encoding=UTF-8
# Roll-over the log once per day
log4j.appender.CATALINA.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.LOCALHOST=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.File=${catalina.base}/logs/localhost.
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.Append=true
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.MANAGER=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MANAGER.File=${catalina.base}/logs/manager.
log4j.appender.MANAGER.Append=true
log4j.appender.MANAGER.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.MANAGER.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.MANAGER.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MANAGER.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.File=${catalina.base}/logs/host-manager.
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.Append=true
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

# Configure which loggers log to which appenders
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost]=INFO, LOCALHOST
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager]=\
  INFO, MANAGER
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager]=\
  INFO, HOST-MANAGER
```

Compared to the official docs, I just changed the 1.st line of the config to: log4j.rootLogger=**FINEST**, CATALINA

(But make sure you do the rest of the steps as well - like copying of the jar files,...)

Comment: Thanks Peter, yes our dev uses log4j for logging, and to support this, I have to configure and put this in our customers location, to get more fine logs, but dont know where to put this...